# import module from a sub folder in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello i am just learning ReactJs, I am trying to import a module from a sub folder in react, here is my folder structure

```
-src
---components
-----layout
-------Header.js
-------Navigation.js
-----fakeAuth.js
```

From the Header.js module, i am trying to import the fakeAuth from the parent (component), but it seems it can't call module or am i just missing something?

I already tried the following

```
import fakeAuth from './fakeAuth'
import fakeAuth from '././fakeAuth'
import fakeAuth from '../../fakeAuth'
```

Still no luck, i know this will be easy for some. Thanks

here i my fakeAuth.js, which is from the react-router-dom tutorial.

```
module.exports  = {
    isAuthenticated: false,
    authenticate(cb) {
      this.isAuthenticated = true;
      setTimeout(cb, 100); // fake async
    },
    signout(cb) {
      this.isAuthenticated = false;
      setTimeout(cb, 100);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Module not found: You attempted to import ../../../fakeAuth.js which falls outside of the project src/ directory.

Comment: can you post what you have in fakeauth.js? Did you export something there?

Comment: Edit: since I saw your edit now, it seems that the import would be '../faceAuth'`

Comment: sorry i edited the location of the fakeAuth.js  with the same path as the layout directory. I can call the fakeAuth module when on the same directory or from a partent, but i cant call it from the sub  directory.

Comment: I added the contents of the fakeAuth.js above.

Comment: @G_S Module not found: Can't resolve '../fakeAuth'

Comment: In your scenario wrt folder structure, ../faceAuth should work. There should be something about your faceauth

Comment: Thanks @G_S it worked!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be `import fakeAuth from '../fakeAuth'`

You just have to go 1 folder up where you have fakeAuth.js file. adding '..' does that.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `module.exports` you can import in the following fashion inside `Header.js`:

```
import { isAuthenticated, authenticate, signout  } from "../fakeAuth";
```

[CodeSandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/8y5mjnym8l)

Comment: Thanks Div, but @G_S helped me out first.

Comment: No problem, probably this helps if you're looking to import the contents of your module ;)